# What's the meaning of these interfaces' prefix?

Tags: juniper

When I watch juniper tutorial  [time at 10:22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Oc_30XDRF8&list=PLol16w-Jodufn6V5DsZA1g7vQZCltGtlx&index=5),

there have Services Interfaces introduction:

[image]

but in my mx480 router, there have several interfaces I don't know prefix meaning.

```
  lt-0/0/10.6          LR3->R0
  lt-0/0/10.7          
  lt-0/0/10.8          
  lt-0/0/10.9          
  lt-0/0/10.11 
  lc-3/0/0             
  lc-3/0/0.32769       
  pfe-3/0/0            
  pfe-3/0/0.16383  
  pfh-3/0/0            
  pfh-3/0/0.16383      
  pfh-3/0/0.16384 
  et-3/0/2.0   
  lt-3/0/10  
  cbp0                 
  demux0               
  dsc 
  esi  
  fxp0.0 
  jsrv                 
  jsrv.1   
  lo0                  
  lo0.0                
  lo0.16384            
  lo0.16385            
  lsi                  
  mtun                 
  pimd                 
  pime                 
  pip0                 
  pp0                  
  tap                  
  vtep
```

Comment: Have you bothered reading JunOS documentation? https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/router-interfaces-overview.html clearly explains their naming scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [link](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/router-interfaces-overview.html) Teun provided is a good resource, but not everything is covered there.  Here is the difference:

- `esi` - Ethernet Segment Identifier, used for EVPN multihoming.
- `pfe` - PFE internal interface.
- `pfh` - FPC internal interface.
- `cbp` - Customer Backbone Port, used for Provider Bridging.
- `jsrv` - Juniper Services Interface, used for things like 802.1X and Captive Portal.
- `pip0` - Provider Instance Port, used for EVPN based Provider Bridging.
- `pp0` - PPPoE interface.
- `vtep` - VXLAN Tunnel End-Point, used for VXLAN routing/forwarding.